# High jumping tactile target or bell

Tags: basketball

I have a kid that plays basketball and he's always running around the house jumping to see what he can reach and to improve his jump height.

Does a "thing" exist that has targets that he can jump for that vary in height that have an audible noise and/or tactile feel?

I could, for example, buy a bunch of small bells and hang them from strings on a pole. Each of the strings having varying lengths from long on one end to short on the other and then attach that pole to a door frame or arch in the house. However I feel that this isn't an original idea and that someone must have come up with a better solution than I've just described. (Or perhaps there's a product and my Google Foo is failing me?)

Comment: Are you seeking this to help him develop his capability, or to provide an alternative outlet for slapping/smacking your doorframes/ceilings/chandeliers/very tall uncle's forehead?

Comment: In the NFL combine - they use something [like this](https://www.amazon.com/Tandem-Vertical-Challenger-Stand-Alone-Measurement/dp/B001BL52MI) (amazon link) for measuring a player's vertical jump height - the idea being you try and hit the "veins" to measure how high you have jumped. Although, having a quick look about, they seem _veeery_ expensive for what is essentially a metal pole and some rotating bits of acrylic :D

Comment: @Nij both. I don't mind him jumping and hitting all those things (his uncle gets annoyed) I just wanted to have something that's more fun for him and his friends to jump at that would at the same time encourage his jumping practice.

Comment: @ImClarky I had completely forgotten about those poles and I don't think that I've ever seen one in person and perhaps just a picture once. Having something like that would be amazing. I'm wondering if an indoor version of that could be created that could be hung off a frame or ceiling that functioned in a similar manner...

Comment: I'll leave this open as seeking equipment for training in a particular sport.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I bought some dog bells online and fashioned a 2x1 as in the image and hung 2 bells per string at varying lengths for him to jump and hit. A very amateur solution but it seems to be working so far and he seems to be enjoying it. It achieves the sport objective of helping him (1) practice jumping and (2) measure improvement over time as he moves to higher ones.

[Slo-mo of the contraption in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDBAzAabSpc)

[image: jumping bells]